# Displaying an NTLM-authenticated web page using QtWebKit

Tags: python, qt, ntlm, qtwebkit, qwebview

My application needs to display a web page which uses NTLM authentication. I've written NTLM authentication methods in the past, but only for passing data to/from a site, as opposed to displaying the site in a QWebView. Similarly, I've written applications in the past (with either Basic or no authentication) which displayed a web page using QWebView with no issue.

I'm struggling however to put these two methods together, to display a web page with NTLM authentication.

Here's my approach:

```
Web_Viewer = QtWebKit.QWebView()
Web_Viewer.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)

URL = "http://www.somewebsitewithNTLMauth.com/pages/Home.aspx"
User = "domain\username"
Password = "Password"

Password_Manager = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
Password_Manager.add_password(None, URL, User, Password)

Authentication_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(Password_Manager)

Opener = urllib.request.build_opener(Authentication_NTLM)

#This is where I get stuck
#Normally I'd load the URL and then show it, as such:

Web_Viewer.load(QtCore.QUrl(URL))
Web_Viewer.show()
```

I understand that Web_Viewer.load() doesn't make use of the NTLM authentication, but I'm unsure how to .show() the page using the authentication.